# Why warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, error-handling

I know that other people have posted the same error, but I can't find anything similar to mine. I have tried implementing some of the solutions but cannot figure out why it is not working.

```
struct list_elem {
        int value;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list{
    struct list_elem *header;
    struct list_elem *footer;
};

struct list_elem *list_elem_malloc(void) {
    struct list_elem *elem;
    elem = malloc( sizeof(struct list_elem) );

    return elem;
}

void list_init(struct list *list) {
    list->header = list_elem_malloc();
    list->footer = list_elem_malloc();

    list->header->prev = NULL;
    list->footer->next = NULL;
    list->header->next = list->footer;   //ERROR on this line
    list->footer->prev = list->header;   //same ERROR on this line
}
```

Why the error ?

I made a typo in struct list_elem, prev and next should be list_elems, not lists!!!! Silly me.

Comment: Indeeed, I typo'd! .. thanks definitely did not see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting mixed up between `struct list` and `struct list_elem`.

It looks like you just need to change:

```
struct list_elem {
    int value;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *next;
};
```

to:

```
struct list_elem {
    int value;
    struct list_elem *prev;
    struct list_elem *next;
};
```

Comment: Thanks .... will accept your answer in 10 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the contents of `list->footer`, which is a `list_elem*` according to your declaration, to `list->header->next`, which is of type `list*`. This is just type-safety at work, the types are not compatible in any way.

You probably intended to declare members `prev` and `next` of `list_elem` as type `list_elem*` instead of `list*`.

Answer (score 1):

`list->footer` is a `struct list_elem *` while `list->header->next` is a `struct list *`, so these assignments won't work:

```
list->header->next = list->footer;   //ERROR on this line
list->footer->prev = list->header;   //same ERROR on this line
```

They are different types and so they are indeed not compatible. It looks like you intended `next` and `prev` to be `struct list_elem *`.